How to check value is Enum Array Type? c#
Enum Type can be checked asobj.PropertyType.IsEnum == true
So how can i check value is Enum Array Type?
// obj = SomeEnum[20]

else if (obj.PropertyType == typeof(Enum[])) // It doesn't work as I think
{
    SetValue(parser, obj);
}


Your question doesn't really make sense as it is. In order to have a PropertyType property, obj would have to be type PropertyInfo, so you couldn't possibly assign an array object to it. We can probably assume what you actually mean but we shouldn't have to, not least because we might get it wrong. Please spend some time in the Help Center to learn how to ask a question properly. You might start here.

All reflection basically works on a Type object. How you get a Type object is irrelevant to how you use it. In your case, if you have a reference to an object and you want to know whether it is an enum array then you can simply call GetType to get a Type object. If you want to use a PropertyType property, as your question implies, then you would have to first get an appropriate PropertyInfo object and then you can determine the type of that property. I'll leave that part to you, because your question is unclear on that and it's not relevant to how you use the Type object anyway.
Once you have an appropriate Type object, you can check whether it is an enum array like this:
if (myType.IsArray && myType.GetElementType().IsEnum)

or like this:
if (myType.GetElementType()?.IsEnum == true)

GetElementType will return null if IsArray is false.
If you're going to use Reflection, I suggest that you do a thorough reading of the documentation for the Type class.
